# How to get an ajax result to a controller in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service which get the value from my ajax call. I want to store that value in a variable and pass that variable to the controller.

```js
angular.module("Data", []).service("DataService", function($http) {
  return {
    Data: function(callback) {
      $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php').success(callback);
    }
  }
})

angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).service("HomeService", function(DataService) {
  var customerData = {}
  return {
    Getdata: DataService.getCustomers(function(results) {
      customerData = results;
      console.log(customerData)
    })
  }
})


angular.module("Home").controller("HomeCntrl", function($scope, HomeService) {

  $scope.Result = HomeService.Getdata;

})
```

I want the data to be stored in `customerData` and I have to pass `customerData` to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use callbacks for this (although it's also possible), not really convenient. [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are everything for such cases. So your code should really be something like this:

```
angular.module("Data", []).service("DataService", function($http) {
    return {
        getCustomers: function() {
            return $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php').then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});

angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).service("HomeService", function(DataService) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return DataService.getCustomers().then(function(data) {
                console.log('customers', data);
                // maybe process data further and return new set
                return data;
            });
        }
    }
});

angular.module("Home").controller("HomeCntrl", function($scope, HomeService) {
    HomeService.getData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.Result = data;
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/7V2mqacof72Ad9cuCivh?p=preview

Comment: The code in the answer is already using promises, not sure what other example you are asking for.

Comment: still i am not getting the value in the controller

Comment: Yes, sorry I was sloppy and missed couple of places. Check updated answer and the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my example:

https://github.com/AlexRepeckiy/todolist/tree/master/app

Follow to service and to controller folder.

Small example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataService', function($scope, DataService) {


    DataService.getData().then(function (results) {
        $scope.tasks = results;
    }); 

}]);

app.factory('DataService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
var exports = {};

exports.getData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/gettask')
        .then(
            function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result.data);
            },
            function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
                console.log('Getting is fail :' + error);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
 };

   return exports;
}]);
```

Without deferred:

```
app.factory('DataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
var exports = {};

exports.getData = function () {


    return $http.get('/gettask')
        .then(
            function (result) {
                return result.data;
            },
            function (error) {

                console.log('Getting is fail :' + error);
        });
 };

   return exports;
}]);
```

Comment: Read about deferred anti-pattern.

Comment: Maybe. This is very old code, this code for example. If you want, we can return $http in fucntion, and by default $http return promiss.

Comment: Exactly, $q is redundant in this case.

Comment: my first service is ajax->second  service BL ->and then from bl  i should get the value  in the controller